Running Laravel Octane with Swoole in Docker: Class "Laravel\Octane\Octane" Not Found Error
I'm trying to run my Laravel application with Octane using Swoole as the application server, all within a Docker container. However, when attempting to start the server, I encounter a fatal error indicating that the class Laravel\Octane\Octane cannot be found.
I've followed the recommended steps for setting up Octane with Swoole, including installing necessary extensions and configuring correctly in the Dockerfile. My current setup is as follows:
Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.3.7-fpm-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache linux-headers

RUN apk --no-cache upgrade && \
    apk --no-cache add bash git sudo openssh  libxml2-dev oniguruma-dev autoconf gcc g++ make npm freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev ssmtp

# PHP: Install php extensions
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN pecl install pcov swoole
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring xml  pcntl gd zip sockets pdo  pdo_mysql bcmath soap
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mbstring xml gd  zip pcov pcntl sockets bcmath pdo  pdo_mysql soap swoole


RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN apk add icu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql intl
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apk add gnupg
#Download the desired package(s)
RUN curl -k -O  https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.10.5.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN curl -k -O  https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.10.1.1-1_amd64.apk

#(Optional) Verify signature, if 'gpg' is missing install it using 'apk add gnupg':
RUN curl -k -O  https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.10.5.1-1_amd64.sig
RUN curl -k -O  https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.10.1.1-1_amd64.sig

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
RUN gpg --verify msodbcsql17_17.10.5.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql17_17.10.5.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN gpg --verify mssql-tools_17.10.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools_17.10.1.1-1_amd64.apk

#Install the package(s)
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.10.5.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.10.1.1-1_amd64.apk

#Extensiones necesarias para poder instalar los drivers de sql server con pecl
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache unixodbc-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev gd-dev

#Instala las extensiones de PHP para SQL Server
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY --from=spiralscout/roadrunner:2.4.2 /usr/bin/rr /usr/bin/rr

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN composer clear-cache
RUN composer install
RUN composer require laravel/octane spiral/roadrunner
COPY .env .env
RUN mkdir -p /app/storage/logs

RUN php artisan octane:install --server="swoole"
CMD php artisan octane:start --server="swoole" --host="192.168.4.234" --port=8001

docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.7"

services:
  gui:
    image: gui
    build: ./gui
    volumes:
      - ./gui:/app
    ports:
      - 5173:80
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - my-network

  api:
    image: api
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

Log container:2024-08-15 11:14:04 
2024-08-15 11:14:04    INFO  Server running…
2024-08-15 11:14:04 
2024-08-15 11:14:04   Local: http://192.168.4.234:8001 
2024-08-15 11:14:04 
2024-08-15 11:14:04   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
2024-08-15 11:14:04 
2024-08-15 11:14:04 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Laravel\Octane\Octane" not found in /app/vendor/laravel/octane/src/Stream.php:56
2024-08-15 11:14:04 Stack trace:
2024-08-15 11:14:04 #0 /app/vendor/laravel/octane/bin/createSwooleServer.php(19): Laravel\Octane\Stream::shutdown(Object(Swoole\Exception))
2024-08-15 11:14:04 #1 /app/vendor/laravel/octane/bin/swoole-server(35): require('/app/vendor/lar...')
2024-08-15 11:14:04 #2 {main}
2024-08-15 11:14:04   thrown in /app/vendor/laravel/octane/src/Stream.php on line 56

I've tried several things to resolve this issue, including:

Ensuring all dependencies are correctly installed.

Checking that the versions of Laravel and Octane are compatible.

Looking out for any dependency conflicts.


Despite my attempts, I haven't been able to find a solution that resolves this problem. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have suggestions on how to proceed?

I think you might have a problem with composer autoloading after installing additional dependencies.
RUN composer require laravel/octane spiral/roadrunner

So to fix your problem, you should add the following code in the end of all your composer operations.
RUN composer dump-autoload -o

But I would recommend not to require additional dependencies in your Dockerfile, because it's bad to modify composer.json and composer.lock during building. So instead consider requiring packages behind the scenes and change your Dockerfile using the following code.
RUN composer clear-cache
RUN composer install
RUN composer dump-autoload -o

